# Who is Maghavat?

Tags: pandavas

It is written in the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata that:

> Then those Indras, of their shorn glory said, 'We shall go from our celestial regions even unto the region of men where salvation is ordained to be difficult of acquisition. But let the gods Dharma, Vayu, **Maghavat**, and the twin Aswins beget us upon our would-be mother. Fighting with men by means of both celestial and human weapons, we shall again come back into the region of Indra.'

Who is **Maghavat**?

Comment: Maghavat is the name of Indra (the Father of Arjuna).

Comment: I would post it as an answer but then it is just one line. Do you want to know anything else?

Comment: @Surya Well, you can provide an explanation for why Indra is called Maghavan.  You can cite verse 2 of this hymn of the Rig Veda: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10023.htm

Comment: @Keshav Well I do not know the Eg veda but I do have a source. I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maghavat (or Maghavan) is Indra, the king of the devas (who is different from the other five Indras imprisoned in the sense that Maghavat is Indra, the father of Arjuna.)

In the Amarakosha, the Sanskrit Lexicon, Maghavat is the third name given to Indra (Indro Marutvan **Maghavan**).

The explanations of the name given are:

- Mahyate Iti (Maghavan) - The Honoured One (is called Maghavat)
- Maghah Saukhyam Asya Asti Iti - Maghavat is he who possesses great powers and luxury

And in the Rgveda, Book 10, Hymn 23, Indra is called Maghavan in the phrase, **Maghair Maghavan** Vrtraha Bhuvat. [Here is the Rgveda 10.23](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10023.htm) (Thanks to Keshav for the link).